# Managing "dataSource" in Bootstrap bootstrap-year-calendar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, datasource

I did a homepage for my dad to manage the vacation flat he owns.
The page is done with bootstrap, and i use bootstrap-year-calendar to show visitors the current status of the flat.

My dad wants to manage the calendar completly himself (which i respect), but unfortunatly he has nearly no computer affinity. In its current state, the following steps needs to be done to add an entry to the calendar:

- download the php-file from the webspace (filezilla)
- open file (notepad++)
- add the timeframe to the dataSource
- save the php-file
- upload the file to the webspace

Additionally you have to substract -1 from the month number of the date to get the calendar to show the timeframe in the right month:

```
dataSource: [
{
id: 0,
name: 'Vacation',
startDate: new Date(2016, 09, 27),
endDate: new Date(2016, 10, 10)
},
{...other entries...}
]
```

he finds that a little complex. Is there a easy way to give him the option to edit that html file?

thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you are looking for some sort of a CMS (Content Management System), perhaps create one of your own. Or, another idea is to download the Notepad++ plugin: `NppFTP`, with this you can directly edit the file and save it (the save will automatically upload it back to the server), this way Filezilla isn't needed anymore.

Comment: thanks! NppFTP will make his life at least one step easier :)